# Maths Issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, math

I am trying to perform a maths equation in SQL to calculate service up time. I have a column with pass counts and a column with fail counts.

I have achieved this sum in VB for the application side and the sum is as follows: `pass / (pass+fail) * 100`.

The results should be on some rows 99.98 but I can't get SQL to give me the same result. I either get 100 or 0 as the result.

This is my SQL query:

```
select pass / sum(pass+fail) * 100 as total, friendlyname from sensors group by pass, friendlyname
```

Example row:

```
Friendly Name  | Pass  | Fail
_____________________________

Cloudflare     | 25527 | 23
```

So as you can see the result should be 99.90 when done on a calculator using above formula but SQL reports this sum as 0.

Really would be grateful for some help!

Comment: Try `* 100.0`, and see what happens.

Comment: @jarlh - very little if it happens after the division.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried the above but it is now showing as 0.0 and 100.0 but still not correct. Thanks

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yeah... I blame lack of coffee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
select
    (pass * 100.0) / sum(pass+fail) as total,
    friendlyname
from sensors
group by friendlyname, pass
```

Comment: Just tried this and it works! Many many thanks, this has been driving me mad for days!

Comment: This _can't_ possibly work, because `pass` does not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Please edit your question and show sample data.

Comment: Yeah I had to add pass in when I run it. No big deal though!

Comment: It makes no sense for `pass` to appear as a group by column and also inside the call to sum.

Answer (score 2):

Make at least one portion of the division a floating point number, to force that precision.  Also, your math seems to be off.  If you want to compute the ratio of passes/fails to the total counts, then sums should appear in both the numerator and denominator.

```
select
    100.0 * sum(pass) / sum(pass+fail) as pass_pct,
    100.0 * sum(fail) / sum(pass+fail) as fail_pct
    friendlyname
from sensors
group by
    friendlyname;
```